# Prove that the least number of dots that must be transplanted (so that the 9 dots will be in 2 straight rows) exceeds four

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

[image]

Prove that the least number of dots that must be transplanted so that the 9 dots will be in 2 straight rows exceeds four.

You can pick arbitrarily any two dots and that will form a line.

What does the correct answer with five moves look like?

Deduction 1: You don't need an equal number of dots separated.

Comment: are we talking about mathematical trees or something else?

Answer (score 2):

No three of the given points lie on a line together, so each of your two lines can contain at most two of the original points. That means you'll have at most four unmoved points and need to move the other five. (In fact, this is the only restriction; you can pick any two pairs of points to make your lines.)

Comment: Why do you mention "two lines"? @Karl

Comment: Isn't that what "2 straight rows" means?